# I'm working on my project and facing a problem in deleting a element in an array of objects

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mongoose-deleteone

I'm working on my project and facing a problem in deleting a element in an array of objects ,the mongoose function run without error but the targated element won't delete at all .Help me with the code.

i want to delete the element of  document(user) having _id->requestedUser and element having the postId -> requestedPost .

[image: here is the img of code]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be that you pass requestedPost object directly as postId value, probably you should get exact id of post from it.

Similar example that works
https://mongoplayground.net/p/CO5qR1RdbuL

Comment: I'm getting the exact id ( checked by printing it in console) ,the whole function run without error but the array element is still there.